# load intent inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android

I have a real big problem implementing loading a intent from inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.
I believe it has to do with the way i have structured my application.

Here is my code:
**VariablesStorage.class**

```
public class VariablesStorage
{
private static VariablesStorage instance;
public static  Context webViewContext;
public  WebView webView;

        public static void initInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            // Create the instance
            instance = new VariablesStorage();
        }
    }
    public static VariablesStorage getInstance()
    {
        // Return the instance
        return instance;
    }
    private VariablesStorage()
    {

    }

public void loadWebView() {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 if (isOnline())
        {
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (url.startsWith("inapp://")) {
                         Intent intent = new Intent(this,profilepictureview.class);
                         intent.putExtra("img",Uri.parse(url).getHost().toString());
                         startActivity(intent);

                        }else
                        {
                            view.getContext().startActivity(
                             new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                        }                       
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) 
                    {

                    }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                    }
                }


            });
            webView.loadUrl(Url);
        }else
        {
            webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html;charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
        }


    }


}
```

and my webview activity where i call `VariablesStorage.getInstance().loadWebView();`

**WebViewActivity.class**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewtab);
 VariablesStorage.getInstance().webViewContext = this;
        VariablesStorage.getInstance().webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            VariablesStorage.getInstance().loadWebView();
}
```

So when i am adding this code inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,profilepictureview.class);
 intent.putExtra("img",Uri.parse(url).getHost().toString());
 startActivity(intent);
```

i am getting this error:

```
The constructor Intent(new WebViewClient(){}, Class<profilepictureview>) is undefined
```

Any help implementing this one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `Intent` doesn't have a constructor that takes `WebViewClient(){}` as a parameter which is what `this` is referring to in this situation. [See Intent Constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28%29)

What you probably want is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(webViewContext,profilepictureview.class);
```

but you will want to initialize `webViewContext` first.

**Edit**
`startActivity` also, needs a `Context`. Try this

```
webViewContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I'll try it and inform you about the results.

Comment: Ok,did it,now its error free but my new activity is not starting...!

Comment: Thank you very much! Last edit solved my problem! Cheers!Thanks to FunkThemonk also!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a static reference to an activity's context is going to cause you problems. All views (including WebView) have getContext(), so use view.getContext() rather than 'this' or 'webViewContext' when creating the Intent.

Also, you're trying to start an activity named 'profilepictureview', which sounds more like a View rather than an Activity?

Comment: Well i think the naming confused you: public class profilepictureview extends Activity{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profilepictureview);
}}